# Horizontal Output Values in C++

Tags: c++

i just start learning C++ and i have a doubt about putting horizontal values in fixed locations and is stated in this image below:

[image]

i'm adding blank spaces (i know it's primitive), but it's just getting way out of control:

```
cout << "\t\t Student ID " << " Student Name " << " Project " << " MidTerm Grade " << " Final Exan " << " Final Result \n";
cout << "\t\t ========== " << " ============ " << " ======= " << " ============= " << " ========== " << " ============ \n";
cout << "\t\t  "<< studentId << "   " << lastName << "." << firstName << "     " << projectGrade << "     " << midtermGrade << "     " << finalexamGrade << "     " <<  "Final Result \n";
```

Anyone got any tips for the rookie?  :)

Comment: Once you get to more advanced stuff, `ncurses` might interest you

Comment: Don't use TAB characters to align your output columns. This will screw up very quickly.  Rather use `std::setw()` to set the width of individual output fields. Additionally use `std::left` and `std::right` to make them left or right aligned to the boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) for a basic program that requires fixed width columns. Mind you that it may quickly become inadequate for more complex formatting. But it should be enough for your case.

Answer (score 0):

The word is [`iomanip`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).  That said, unless someone is making you do this, you have better things to study; precise textual output formatting is neither very common in (modern) programs nor nearly so important as algorithms and data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with fixed size, corresponding to the maximum number of characters in one line. Then you can add spaces is places you want them i.e. between categories. Put data in places you need them and the rest keep with spaces.

```
char head [16]="Category  Value";
char separator [16] = "========  =====";
char test [16] = "test       test";
printf(head);
printf("\n"); //newline
printf(separator);
printf("\n");
printf(test);
```

Result:

```
Category  Value
========  =====
test       test
```

Comment: Of course you can add data to the tables or change these values from within the code by simply calling the appropriate table's index, i.e test[0] = a will change first test  in aest so the test table will be like: aest       test.